# Minimum value of this trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Find the minimum value of this function for $0\lt \theta \lt \pi$ $$y = 3\sin{\theta} + \text{cosec}^3\theta$$

What I want to specifically ask is about use of inequality rules in this function.

I used the rule: $$\text{if } a\lt b \text{ and } c\lt d \implies a + c\lt b + d$$

$$0\lt3\sin\theta\lt 3\text{ }\forall\text{ } 0\lt \theta \lt \pi$$
Also $$1\lt\text{cosec}^3\theta\lt \infty$$
So shouldn't these two inequations combine to give $$1\lt3\sin{\theta} + \text{cosec}^3\theta\lt\infty$$
But the correct answer is 4. Did I do any mistake or does this rule not apply here?

I'm not looking for solution to this problem, I just want to know why this method fails here.

Comment: Your rule regarding $a,b,c,d$ is incorrect. Have you tried with some examples? Take for instance $a=1\,,b=5\,,c=2\,,d=3$. Rather $a<b$ and $c<d$ implies $a+c<b+d$—is that what you meant?

Comment: The sum of the two inequalities $0<3\sin\theta<3$ and $1<\mbox{cosec}^3\theta<\infty$ into $1<3\sin\theta+\mbox{cosec}^3\theta<\infty$ is technically correct, but you need to consider that as $3\sin\theta$ changes value, so does $\mbox{cosec}^3\theta$. For example, take $f(x)$ with $1<f(x)<\infty$, then $-\infty<-f(x)<\infty$, but the sum is $-\infty<0<\infty$, the minimum of the sum is 0, even though the two functions $f(x),-f(x)$ had infinitely big negative values

Comment: @JackLeGrüß yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you got that the sum of the function should lie in that interval. However, this tells nothing about what the minimum value of the sum can be.

**An analogy:** Say you are in your home then I can derive from that premise that you are in some room of your home but I can't really say which room you are in. The only thing I know is that you must be fixed in space of your house.

Similarly, this inequality doesn't really tell us how big or small the function can actually be. Only where the values of it can lie in.

For example:

$$ -2 < \sin \theta < 2$$

Is a true inequality for all $\theta$, however this does not mean that $2$ is maximum of $ \sin \theta$

---

**Clarifications:**

Inequalities are indeed a difficult subject.. however if you boil it down to fundamentals then you can make it simple.

For example consider the set $(1,3)$ this is equivalent to the inequality:

$$ 1 < x < 3$$

To show that this problem arises even for non trignometric functions , consider the function $f(x) = -x^2$

It is pretty simple to see that:

$$ f(x) \leq 0 $$

For all $ x \in R$

However, this doesn't mean the inequality business is completely useless. There are still some nice conclusions which you can make.

For example, consider the function $ f(x) = x \ln x $, from our days in calculus we know the exact methodologies for finding the maxima and minimum.

$$ f'(x) = \ln x + 1$$

Or for the maxima or a minima,

$$ \ln x = -1$$

Which suggests $ x = \frac{1}{e}$

And, from the second derivative test, $ f''(x)$ is positive at $x=e$. Hence this means that it is a minimum occurs here, since this is the only turning point in the graph, it must be absolute minima.

Hence we can boldly make the statement that:

$$ \frac{1}{e} \leq f(x)$$

Setting a lower bound for the function.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't that make any equality complex? How can we ever predict that the interval is the actual range of the function? Just like $-2\lt\sin\theta\lt2$, if we didn't knew better we couldn't have predicted that the actual range of that function. Also, does the inequality rule that I mentioned, only provide the possible interval for the function but not the actual range?

Comment: And I believe that this problem arises only for trigonometric functions. What if interval for an algebric expression was given: $-3\lt x\lt3$. Does that mean x acquires every value in the interval $(-3,3)$?

Comment: I have edited the answer and showed a place where inequality turns out to give more valuable information

Answer (score 3):

The property $y>1$ is true, but it does not give a minimal value because you need also to show that the minimal value occurs, as in the following reasoning.

By AM-GM $$y\geq4\sqrt[4]{\sin^3x\cdot\frac{1}{\sin^3x}}=4.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{\pi}{2},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: If $y\gt 1$ doesn't imply that it is the the minimum value then how can you say that $y\ge 4$ does?

Comment: @Eyy boss See please my post. I explained there: we can get a value $y=4$, while the value $y=1$ we can not get.

Answer (score 0):

For $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi,$  $cosec \theta \ge 1$ (min occurs when $\sin \theta$ is maximum i.e $\sin \theta = 1$).

Say, $cosec \theta = 1+x, $ where $x \ge 0$

$y = \frac{3}{1+x} + (1+x)^3= 1+x^3+3x(1+x)+\frac{3}{1+x} = 4 + x^3+3x(1+x)-\frac{3x}{1+x}$

$\implies y = 4 + x^3+3x(1+x)-\frac{3x}{1+x} = 4 + x^3 + \frac{3x(x^2+2x)}{1+x} \ge 4$

The min value of $4$ occurs when $x = 0$ (i.e $cosec\theta = 1 = \sin\theta$).